# how to Extract word combination from an string

Tags: javascript

want to find a way  to search  for words in a string and return them In the same order
so here is an example I am  searching for dog and cat :
let story = "The **dog** ran away, The **cat** is unhappy,**cat** watched the sky and saw a**dog**"

 result should be :
`return dog cat cat dog`   notice the last one on the story string is "adog" not a "dog" we just want to return the value whenever the dog combination appears.

a simple summary of the text above:
 how to return a specific combination of characters in a string when they are surrounded by other characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), using the `|` to separate the strings to search for.

> The [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method retrieves the result of matching a string against a regular expression.

```js
let story = "The dog ran away, The cat is unhappy,cat watched the sky and saw adog" 

const search = /dog|cat/g;

console.log(story.match(search));

// will result in ["dog", "cat", "cat", "dog"]
```

Comment: Woah amazing  /dog|cat/g its regex right ?  what are some articles that can help me in these situations? thank you in advance.

Comment: @alireza I added a link to MDN in the answer, and another one with tons of info is https://www.regular-expressions.info/ Also a good one to test regular expressions is https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

**In string format:**

```js
let str = 'a dog see a cat, also cat and adog ..';

let filtered = str.split(' ').filter(x => x.match(/(dog|cat)/g)).join(' ');

console.log(filtered.match(/(dog|cat)/g).join(','));
```

**In array format:**

```js
let str = 'a dog see a cat, also cat and adog ..';

let filtered = str.split(' ').filter(x => x.match(/(dog|cat)/g)).join(' ');

console.log(filtered.match(/(dog|cat)/g));
```

Here, see the first comment:

[find and return string with a specific word in it in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977310/find-and-return-string-with-a-specific-word-in-it-in-js)